# Centralized GIT workflow/deployment - Repository Initialization and Feature Branches

Tags: git, workflow, branch, centralized, unfuddle

OK, I just want to check the workflow of my GIT setup is correct and I understand it fully before I begin to use it properly. I'm following [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) workflow and this topic is just going to start with the initialization and creating feature branches then when I'm confident with that I'll create a new topic for Releases and Hotfixes. Hopefully this will help other people to who are looking to use GIT in a similar workflow.

There are 3 developers, let's call them A, B and C who will all work on their local machine, we have 4 remote servers - 'Development', 'Staging', 'Production' and Unfuddle (as the centralized server). Developer A has the directory of files on their local machine.

So, i'm thinking the workflow will be as follows.

Firstly, I need to create the repository on Unfuddle and locally then push my files to the Unfuddle server.

1. Create a repository in Unfuddle called 'website' and give it the abbreviation 'web'
2. Create an SSH Keypair on 'Development', 'Staging' and 'Production' servers and add them to Unfuddle account.
3. Developer A initializes a Git repository in their document root:

   `git init`
4. Associate the Unfuddle repository with developer A's local one and designate it as an upstream server:

   `git remote add unfuddle git@subdomain.unfuddle.com:username/web.git`

   `git config remote.unfuddle.push refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`
5. Developer A adds all files to index

   `git add *`
6. Developer A commits all files

   `git commit -am 'initial commit'`
7. Developer A pushes locally made commits to Unfuddle Git repository.

   `git push unfuddle master`

I should now see all of my files within my Unfuddle repository. Developers B and C may now clone the repository to get a copy of the website files.

```
`git clone git@subdomain.unfuddle.com:username/web.git`
```

**Feature Branches:**

Each developer can now begin creating feature branches using the following workflow:

1. `git checkout -b develop`
2. `git checkout -b feature\test develop`
3. Make any code changes
4. `git commit -a -m "Make test code changes"`
5. `git checkout develop`
6. `git merge --no-ff feature\test`
7. `git branch -d feature\test`
8. `git push unfuddle develop`

OK so the next part I'm unsure of. We have pushed the feature changes to the centralized Unfuddle server, however the other developers need to get the changes, therefore would they need to create a 'develop' branch and then do `git pull unfuddle develop`? I've read a fetch and merge is better than pull, is this the case? If so, would it be `git fetch unfuddle develop` then `git merge develop` ?

Comment: I think you want a forward slash - feature/test etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds solid.

With regards to `pull` vs `fetch`, I think that if you know exactly what a pull does (`fetch`/`merge`), you can use it freely. A lot of newcomers to git use `pull` without understanding what it does, but it seems like you grasp it. I'd just make sure your team knows what the difference is.

The only step I'm not seeing is the deployment to your webservers - those should be doing a `fetch`/`merge` or `pull` on updates as well. You may want to start off with this process being manual and consider automating it in the future. You should be able to do that with git hooks (they should be supported in Unfuddle). Those scripts will vary on the type of servers that you're running.

Comment: Thanks Nic. Am I right in thinking each developer must pull from the central server before beginning any work or only when they create a new branch from 'develop'?

Comment: Here's where you see a little bit of a difference between pull and fetch. If you're syncing repos to get caught up with the latest, you can pull. If you're in the middle of working on a file/project that others may be working on, it is better to fetch first then plan your merge. Otherwise, the pull may fail if it isn't a fast-forward, so you'd have to create a patch or commit your changes before doing so.

Comment: Also - if you're doing most changes on topic branches and then merging to develop and pushing, you shouldn't have too many issues with merges because active work is being done on topic branches.

Comment: When you say others may be working on do you mean developer A could create a feature branch and developer B could also work on the same branch? If so, would A have to commit it to central repo then B pull it from there and begin working on it?

Comment: @DerekCarlisle yes, they should always route through the central repo first, and staying in branches keeps your log clean.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions but am I right in thinking you should always be working in a feature, release or hot fix branch and never in develop or master?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19235/discussion-between-derek-carlisle-and-nic)