# Centralized GIT workflow/deployment - Release Branch

Tags: git, shell, workflow, branch, release

Following on from my previous question regarding feature branches with you can find here [Centralized GIT workflow/deployment - Repository Initialization and Feature Branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13247085/centralized-git-workflow-deployment-repository-initialization-and-feature-bran) I've got a few questions about 'Release branches'.

Firstly, I'll go through the workflow:

The state of develop is ready for the “next release” and we have decided that this will become version 1.0

`git checkout -b release-1.0 develop`

`./bump-version.sh 1.0`

OK my first question. Do I need to create the bump-version script or can I download it from somewhere? What does it specifically do and where does it need to be installed?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused about your question. Do you need a script that can tell you the actual version number?

You could try `git describe master` for instance, which will give you a specific name from the latest tag you created. Take a look on the [Preparing a release section](http://git-scm.com/book/ch5-3.html#Generating-a-Build-Number) on the Pro Git book.

Comment: I'm following http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ and it says to run ./bump-version.sh so I'm trying to figure out what this actually is.

Comment: As it is written in the tutorial you linked: *"After creating a new branch and switching to it, we bump the version number. Here, bump-version.sh is a fictional shell script that changes some files in the working copy to reflect the new version. (This can of course be a manual change—the point being that some files change.) Then, the bumped version number is committed."*

Comment: Yes I saw that but which files are changed and what to? Can I get the script from somewhere?

Comment: No, there's no such script, because *"bump-version.sh is a fictional shell script "*. It's just an example :-) Each project has its own relase process that updates the version number, you have to develop your custom process.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of your previous question you are attempting to follow: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Have you tried to use git-flow? It was designed to help with these questions.

https://github.com/nvie/gitflow

Comment: I wanted to avoid gitflow so that I could learn GIT as much as possible without it doing it all for me.

Answer (score 0):

"What bump-version.sh does" would depend on your build process. For instance if you use `maven`, it might `sed` your pom to set the version. If you use `sbt`, you could keep the version setting in a separate `version.sbt` file and the script could just overwrite the whole file.